# Styling DEM in QGIS: different colors for sea and land if elevation is 0 meters

Tags: qgis, raster, symbology, dem, style

I am currently working with a 15-ARCSEC DEM of Central Europe in QGIS and there are several areas that have an elevation of 0 m. This leads to the problem, that the software is unable to differentiate between land and sea and gives both the same colour. I have tried to cut the DEM by a mask layer, so that it's only on land, but unfortunately now the whole globe outside the original DEM is also calculated to be at an elevation of 0 m. this is especially frustrating, since areas with negative elevation can easily be coloured differently by assigning the respective value in the symbology.

[image: Here you can see the inevitable problem, when working in an area like The Netherlands.]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me what you want to do. To me, it makes sense that a DTM does not manage to distinguish between sea level and areas < [vertical resolution of DTM] above sea level If it is just a display issue, you can try to filter out everything at 0m and put your polygon land maps behind with whatever color you want for 0 meters. If the issue creates some problems for some analysis you want to do, you need to explain a bit more.

Answer (score 6):

Get a polygon layer representing the sea, put this over the DEM and give it a color for the water body. Then assign a different color to the DEM for elevation = 0.

If you don't have a polygon for teh sea, use the land polygon you have and set its style to [inverted polygons](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#inverted-polygon-renderer).

*Here, I used the pre-installed worldmap in QGIS (type `world` in the coordinates field) for `Inverted Polygon` layer rendering style*
[image]

[image: +]

Comment: This is exactly how I handle water bodies in general (not just those at sea level).